# Win32 GUI demo app to Java (applet) GUI

Tags: java, winapi, swing, awt, applet

I have a trivial legacy C win32 GUI app that makes calls to the win32 GUI API. I have reqritten the C demo app as a Java applet, and I now want to now change the graphics portion to its Java equivalent.

I have gone through the graphics functions and this is the list of win32 API functions being used:

- CreateEllipticRgn
- CreateFont
- CreatePen
- CreatePolygonRgn
- CreateRectRgn
- CreateSolidBrush
- CreateSolidBrush
- DeleteObject
- DrawEdge
- ExtTextOut
- FillRect
- FrameRect
- GetTextExtentPoint32
- GetTextMetrics
- InflateRect
- LineTo
- MoveToEx
- PtInRect
- Rectangle
- RectVisible
- SelectObject
- SetBkColor
- SetPixelV
- SetTextAlign
- SetTextColor

I have not yet done any GUI programming so am not quite sure which Java GUI framework to use - there appears to be so many.

Can anyone help with:

1. recommending which GUI framework to use for my applet
2. providing the java Graphics functions that map to the Win32 API functions listed above?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious choice would be Swing, but don't expect to have a one-to-one mapping between Win32 GUI APIs and Swing.

In Win32 you have functions that use handles as object identifiers; in Swing you have a real OO GUI framework. Furthermore, the way events are handled is quite different.

To do the port you'll have to understand how Win32 & Swing work first. For Win32, I'd recommend the "Programming Windows" books, by Charles Petzold. For Swing, try Core Java Vol. I, by Horstmann & Cornell. Trying to do it before grasping their concepts will be frustrating and time consuming.